# Getting an image off harddrive dynamically to display in gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to grab an image off my hard-drive dynamically but i cannot because even tho the dynamic path is created correctly, it is not displaying.

The reason to this is because i am creating a back-end system for a website. It will be hosted on the same hard-drive but the back-end needs access to the images added by the users.

This is so we can screen the things users upload before making them "live" on the website.

I used this code on the main site and adapted it to work on the back end but it will not work.

When i display the page the image does not show but if i right click the area the image should be then it will allow me to copy link and when i put this in the address bar and the image shows.. I'm stumped :(

Can sombody look at my code and see where am going wrong

the code below:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" style="background-color: #f3f3f3;">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <asp:DataList ID="_propertyImagesList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="16">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="popup-gallery">
                  <a id="imageLink" href='<%# Eval("ImagePath","file:///C:/Development/main website/main website/PropertyImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" class="thumbnail" style="margin: 10px; min-height: 140px; min-width: 140px;">
                      <asp:Image ID="_propertyImage" ImageUrl='<%# Bind("ThumbPath", "file:///C:/Development/main website/main website/PropertyImages/{0}") %>' runat="server" CssClass="img-responsive" />
                  </a>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </div>
</div>
```

c#

```
    protected void GetPropertyImages(int propertyId)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPropertyImages", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlDataReader rdr;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PropertyId", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = propertyId;

        conn.Open();
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        _propertyImagesList.DataSource = rdr;
        _propertyImagesList.DataBind();

        rdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Anything with file:// in is super bad and shouldn't be used, ever... ever! You need to provide us with your c# code that binds the DataList and personally I'd use ItemDataBound event to bind the image urls

Comment: Iv added the c#. the c# basically asks the sql for the end of the path details so the markup can find and display the images. I never use file:// but i wanted to test it and even that didnt work. I just cant seem to find a way.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'd do and have done on many projects, its untested so there maybe one or two things you need to tweek to suit your setup. I'm guessing that C:\Development\main website\main website is the root of your website.

NB: I also changed the ID of the DataList, this is inline with the Resharper's naming convention.

```
<asp:DataList ID="PropertyImageList" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="PropertyImageList_ItemDataBound" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CellPadding="16">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="popup-gallery">
            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="PropertyImageLink" CssClass="thumbnail" Style="margin: 10px; min-height: 140px; min-width: 140px;">
                <asp:Image runat="server" ID="PropertyImage" CssClass="img-responsive" />
            </asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

C#

```
protected void PropertyImageList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    var data = e.Item.DataItem as DbDataRecord;
    if (data == null)
        return;

    var link = e.Item.FindControl("PropertyImageLink") as HyperLink;
    var image = e.Item.FindControl("PropertyImage") as Image;

    if (link == null || image == null)
        return;

    image.ImageUrl = "~/PropertyImages/" + data["ImagePath"];
    link.NavigateUrl = "~/PropertyImages/" + data["ThumbPath"];
}
```

Comment: Main website is not the root of the website that this is being implemented. I am using it in a diffrent solution but both are on the same hard-drive/server. This is why am defining the whole. Will this still work if i adjust the url to a full c:/ kind of path?

Comment: I'm just going to say no! If the PropertyImages directory isn't browsable then your solution will not work unless you are using the server... this is bad bad practise. You could make the PropertyImage folder a virtual directory perhaps?!?

Comment: I have done it with downloading the images as a file? but i cannot get them to display on the website. I have heard of this virtual directory but am unsure how to implement it